# Rails: Issues with bootstrap modal (it won't close, and the background won't fade to dark)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am working on a Rails site that uses twitter bootstrap.

When a user click on a link, the site sends a ajax call to a controller and the controller render a partial(the modal).

.js file:

```
$ ->
    $('#play').click (e) ->
        e.preventDefault()
        $.post "/hype", (data) ->
            $("#hhh").html data //a dummy div to put the data (I dont use this)
```

items controller:

```
def hype_modal
    @item = Item.where(:end => Time.zone.now .. '2040-12-28 08:08:00').order("launch ASC").limit(1).first #Item.find_by_rank(1)
    render "items/partial/_hypemodal"
  end
```

The partial(modal) (items/partial/_hypemodal.html.erb)

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="tr">
    <div class="modal-body"><%= raw @item.link %></div>
</div>
```

The link works just fine (I can click it, and the modal opens). The problem is that it won't close if I click outside the modal (this is normal behaviour, so it should work...). The other problem is that the background won't dim (get darker).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="tr">
<div class="modal-body"><%= raw @item.link %></div>
```

For the closing issue, are you getting any errors from the console?

Comment: Hi! It didn't work and I am not getting any errors either, hmmm?